# Kivy scaling text based on window height and width

Tags: python, kivy

I want to scale a text inside a button or label based on the window height, but limited by window width. The following works:

```
font_size: self.height - dp(15)
```

However the text can exceed the width of the button or label, so I want to limit it with something like:

```
font_size: self.height - dp(15) if self.texture_size[0] < self.width else (self.width*2)/(self.height+0.1)
```

Unfortunately this has to problem that when >= texture_size[0] it will become smaller, but then when the text is smaller again, it is < self.width. So it end up stuck in a loop, which results in [CRITICAL] [Clock] error.

To give a more clear picture, the text in the red bar should be as big as possible, but not exceed the button width:
[image: Kivy_text-scaling]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a scale transformation to shrink the text if it is too large, which will avoid the race:

```
<ScaleLabel@Label>:
    _scale: 1. if self.texture_size[0] < self.width else float(self.width) / self.texture_size[0]
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Scale:
            origin: self.center
            x: self._scale or 1.
            y: self._scale or 1.
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
```

This does scale everything on the canvas, however. So if you're trying to draw a background or something, make sure it is outside the `PushMatrix`/`PopMatrix`. For example, if you wanted to use this with a `Button`, you could rewrite `Button`'s kv rules:

```
<-ScaleButton@Button>:
    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
    _scale: 1. if self.texture_size[0] < self.width else float(self.width) / self.texture_size[0]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        BorderImage:
            border: self.border
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image
        PushMatrix
        Scale:
            origin: self.center
            x: self._scale or 1.
            y: self._scale or 1.
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_color if self.disabled else self.color
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
        PopMatrix
```

I created a usage example as a gist: https://gist.github.com/kived/862db38078170ec0ef83

Comment: This seems extremely complicated. Surely there must be something builtin that is pythonic and simple to use.

Comment: This no longer works in kivy 2.2.1. Also it only scales when decreasing width of window, not height.

Answer (score 1):

As another option, I made this [kivy label with font that resizes](https://github.com/mishaeel/kivy_font_resizing_widgets/blob/main/font_resizing_label.py) based on the window size before I discovered this impressive solution from @kitti. I believe it gives the same result as kitti's code, except in python instead of kv language.

Here is a code-y example you can run just to see if it works, but for developing apps, importing the FontRenamingLabel class and creating `Labels` using it may be easier (see link above).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class FontResizingLabel(Label):

    original_window_size = Window.system_size
    original_font_size = '40sp'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FontResizingLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_pre_resize=self.resize_font)
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.resize_font)
        self.font_size = self.original_font_size

    def resize_font(self, *args):

        fs = int(self.original_font_size[:2])
        wss = Window.system_size
        oss = self.original_window_size
        if (wss[0] / oss[0]) >= (wss[1] / oss[1]):
            ratio = wss[1] / oss[1]
            new_fs = fs * ratio
            new_fs_str = str(new_fs) + 'sp'
            self.font_size = new_fs_str
        elif (wss[0] / oss[0]) < (wss[1] / oss[1]):
            ratio = wss[0] / oss[0]
            new_fs = fs * ratio
            new_fs_str = str(new_fs) + 'sp'
            self.font_size = new_fs_str     
        else:
            pass

class Frame(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class FontResizingApp(App):

    kv_lang_styling = '''
<Frame>
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (.5, .5, .5, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [4]
        pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': .451}
        size_hint: (.2, .08)

        FontResizingLabel:
            text: 'Sample!'
            center: self.parent.center
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            bold: True
'''

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(self.kv_lang_styling)
        return Frame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FontResizingApp().run()
```