# How do I use kivy to get my text font size to adjust to fill button width?

Tags: python, kivy, font-size

I'm learning kivy by myself and have been playing with simple elements to get to know it better. I want to get the text in a button to resize based on the size of the button (which resizes based on the window size).

Since I want the button size to be dynamic, simply setting the font size doesn't work. I tried using font_size: self.width*0.3, but that simply sets the height of the font, not the width of the whole text.

my .kv file:

```
text: 'text'

font_size: 50

halign: 'center'

valgin: 'middle'

color: 1, 1, 1, 1

background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1

size_hint: 0.5, 0.5

pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

Comment: A similar question is answered at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504049/kivy-scaling-text-based-on-window-height-and-width/31504536#31504536). If you use a large `font_size`, this will scale it down to fit your `Button` size.