# Kivy: How to properly bind a canvas matrix operation in a child widget in Python code?

Tags: python, canvas, widget, kivy, scaling

I am working with the [calculator tutorial from RealPython](https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/) and I want to scale the canvas of my Label child widget whenever the width of the parent widget is less than the texture_size in my Label widget. In my code, my Lable is in a layout and therefore its position and size are based on its parent.

I am taking some code in [KvLang that scales a child widget well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504049/kivy-scaling-text-based-on-window-height-and-width)  and implementing it in Python to get a better understanding of coding with Kivy.

Whenever the parent widget position changes, I call my child's check_canvas() method to run its canvas instructions and there I call Scale but it appears to be doing nothing to the text in my Label.

How can I resize the canvas of myTextInput using Scale in Python code? (I am purposely avoiding KvLang)

Here is the portion of my code that involves what I am trying to accomplish

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import PushMatrix,PopMatrix,Scale

class myTextInput(Label):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myTextInput,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def check_canvas(self):   
        if self.texture_size[0] < self.width:
            self._scale = 1
        else:
            self._scale = float(self.width) / self.texture_size[0]

        self.text = 'my scale text here (%d, %.2f)' % (self.width, self._scale)

        with self.canvas.before:

            PushMatrix()
            Scale(
                origin = self.center,
                x = self._scale or 1,
                y = self._scale or 1
                )
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.operators = ["/", "*", "+", "-"]
        self.last_was_operator = None
        self.last_button = None
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.solution = myTextInput(font_size= main_layout.height * 0.5)

        def callback_size(instance, value):
            print('The widget', instance, 'sized to', value)
            print('The widget', instance, 'texture_size[0] is', instance.texture_size[0])

            #What I have noted here is that the texture_size[0] and size
            #are responsive but not _scale and canvas operations.
            #I made check_canvas() to 'enforce' a check on _scale and canvas operation but
            #although now I see _scale changing, canvas operations are not showing any result

            instance.check_canvas() 

            print('The widget', instance, '_scale is', instance._scale)           

        self.solution.bind(size = callback_size)                
        main_layout.add_widget(self.solution)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line:

```
self.solution = myTextInput(font_size= main_layout.height * 0.5)
```

Sets the `font_size` of `myTextInput` to half the height of `main_layout` at the moment that line is executed. Since that line is executed in the `build()` method, before `main_layout` is actually displayed, its `height` is the default `100`, so the `font_size` is set to `50`. That `font_size` will not change, regardless of the size of `myTextInput`. The `Scale` instruction only changes the size of `myTextInput`, not the `font_size`. If you set in `kv`:

```
font_size: main_layout.height * 0.5
```

(Assuming that `main_layout` is defined in your `kv`) Then the `font_size` would be adjusted whenever the `height` of `main_layout` changed. That is compliments of the `kv` language. If you do it in Python, you must take care  of it yourself. You can do that by adding code to adjust the `font_size` in your `check_canvas()` method:

```
def check_canvas(self, main_layout):
    if self.texture_size[0] < self.width:
        self._scale = 1
    else:
        self._scale = float(self.width) / self.texture_size[0]

    self.text = 'my scale text here (%d, %.2f)' % (self.width, self._scale)

    # adjust the font_size
    self.font_size = main_layout.height * 0.1

    with self.canvas.before:

        PushMatrix()
        Scale(
            origin = self.center,
            x = self._scale or 1,
            y = self._scale or 1
            )
    with self.canvas.after:
        PopMatrix()
```

Note that the modified `check_canvas()` takes `main_layout` as an argument, so the call to this method must change in your `callback_size()` to:

```
instance.check_canvas(main_layout)
```

I have changed the `font_size` factor to `0.1` from `0.5` just because that seems quite large.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion on changing font_size is great. What I want Scaling to do is scale down the size of the myTextInput whenever the width of it is less than the texture_size[0]. Effectively, it will  "decrease" the font_size and keep myTextInput in view and not get truncated whenever I resize the App window. I would like to implement Scaling with this problem well. My current code is missing something in its implementation to scale myTextInput.

Comment: Is using the `Scale` matrix a requirement?

Comment: Yes. I should have explicitly stated this in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that still uses the `Matrix` as your code does, but calculates a font size to fit the width of the `myTextInput`:

```
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
.
.
.

def check_canvas(self):
    if self.texture_size[0] < self.width:
        self._scale = 1
    else:
        self._scale = float(self.width) / self.texture_size[0]

    self.text = 'my scale text here (%d, %.2f)' % (self.width, self._scale)

    # adjust the font_size
    self.font_size = self.calculate_font_to_fit(self.text, self.width)

    # need to clear the canvas instructions, or they just keep accumulating
    self.canvas.before.clear()
    self.canvas.after.clear()

    with self.canvas.before:
        PushMatrix()
        Scale(
            origin = self.center,
            x = self._scale or 1,
            y = self._scale or 1
            )
    with self.canvas.after:
        PopMatrix()

def calculate_font_to_fit(self, text, width):
    # use core.text.Label to calculate size of a Label with given font and text
    self.core_label = CoreLabel(text=text, font_name=self.font_name, font_size = self.font_size)
    self.core_label.refresh()
    curr_width = self.core_label.texture.width
    new_font_size = int(self.font_size)
    if curr_width > width:
        # reduce font size
        while curr_width > width:
            new_font_size -= 1
            self.core_label = CoreLabel(text=text, font_name=self.font_name, font_size = new_font_size)
            self.core_label.refresh()
            curr_width = self.core_label.texture.width
    elif curr_width < width:
        # increase font size
        while curr_width < width:
            old_font_size = new_font_size
            new_font_size += 1
            self.core_label = CoreLabel(text=text, font_name=self.font_name, font_size = new_font_size)
            self.core_label.refresh()
            curr_width = self.core_label.texture.width
        new_font_size = old_font_size
    return new_font_size
```

Comment: Yes, your code produces the results I intended to do with the Scale on canvas of myTextInput. The canvas code can be commented out and the font will size properly. I was essentially trying to [rewrite this code] (https://gist.github.com/kived/862db38078170ec0ef83) into Python code. If you run this code, you'll see that the text in the customized Label 'resizes' on width change not due to an explicit font_size change but a shrinking/scaling of the canvas where the text gets prinited. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Note that in the referenced code, there is a line: `font_size: self.height * 0.5`. But it is in the kv language. The `kv` language sets up a binding so that the `font_size` gets adjusted whenever the `height` of the `ScaleLabel` gets changed. Your line: `self.solution = myTextInput(font_size= main_layout.height * 0.5)` does not set up a binding, so the `font_size` does not get changed.

Comment: So the `font_size` is getting adjusted by that binding that `kv` sets up, not by the `Scale` matrix.